$A, B,$ and $AB$ densely defined linear operators $\rightarrow (AB)^* \supseteq B^*A^*$

$A, B,$ and $AB$ densely defined linear operators $\rightarrow (AB)^* \supseteq B^*A^*$

This is Exercise 1 from X.1 of Conway's FA. It should be easy, but I'm a bit confused.
If $x \in \mathcal{D}(B^*A^*)$, then is it true that $x \in \mathcal{D}(A^*)$? If that's true that means
$$a \mapsto \langle Aa, k \rangle$$
is bounded linear functional on $\mathcal{D}(A)$. Where do I go from here? I can see by hand-waving why the proposition should be true but don't know how to implement the fact that $B$ is densely defined.
Thank you.

By definition the domain of $D(B^A^)$ consists of $x\in D(A^*)$ such that $A^x\in D(B^).$

The domain of $(AB)^*$ consists of elements $x$ such that the linear functional $D(AB)\ni y\mapsto \langle ABy,x\rangle $ is bounded, i.e. of the form  $\langle ABy,x\rangle=\langle y,z\rangle.$ In such case we have $(AB)^*x=z.$ Let's study $x\in D(B^*A^*).$ Then $x\in D(A^*)$ and $A^*x\in D(B^*).$ Thus for $y\in D(AB)$ we get
$$\langle ABy,x\rangle =\langle By,A^*x\rangle =\langle y, B^*A^*x\rangle$$ Therefore $x\in D((AB)^*)$ and  $(AB)^*x=B^*A^*x.$ Hence $B^*A^*\subset (AB)^*.$

Yes, $x \in \mathcal D(B^* A^*)$ means $x \in \mathcal D(A^*)$ and $A^* x \in \mathcal D(B^*)$. $A^* x$ is the linear functional taking $y \in \mathcal D(A)$ to $\langle x, Ay \rangle$, and $B^* A^* x$ is the linear functional taking
$z \in \mathcal D(B)$ to $\langle A^* x, B z \rangle$.
If $z \in \mathcal D(AB) \subseteq \mathcal D(B)$, we also have $Bz \in \mathcal D(A)$, and so
$$\langle B^* A^* x, z \rangle = \langle A^* x, B z \rangle = \langle x, A B z \rangle$$
